# Audio queue starts failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio-streaming, audiostreamer

I have encountered that while streaming song with AudioStreamer following error occured:

```
Audio queue start failed. err: hwiu 1752656245
```

this error occured in the following code

```
err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
if (err)
{
    [self failWithErrorCode:AS_AUDIO_QUEUE_START_FAILED];
    return;
}
```

where audioQueue is object of AudioQueueRef. What to do to prevent going into if condition??
What could be the error? I am using AudioStreamer example of github?

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer to this links?

Second one is most interesting.

[Audio queue start failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490786/audio-queue-start-failed)

[AudioQueue fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117776/audioqueue-fails-to-start)

http://s272.codeinspot.com/q/881582

Try if you have referred to it.

This may help you.